# Microphone not working after water spilled on iPad

Tags: ipad, facetime, damage

I accidentally spilled water on my iPad. I cleaned it up right away and it's perfectly fine. I can hear stuff and it turns on but when I call people, they can't hear me.

Answer (score 1):

If some water got in the microphone it may still be damp.  You could try putting the iPad overnight in a sealed bag with a couple of handfuls of rice which will take up any dampness.